# MPAndroidChart click on pieChart Slices

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How to control click on each slice in a pie chart of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)? I know that we can control click on pie chart, but I want clicking on slice of chart and find which slice is clicked?

Answer (score 11):

Your activity must implement the OnChartValueSelectedListener interface.

As written in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart) "let your class that should receive the callbacks implement this interface and set it as a listener to the chart"

```
public class MyActivity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener{
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(){
        // do stuff
    }
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h){
        Log.i("I clicked on", String.valueOf(e.getXIndex()) );
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        (PieChart)chart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        ...
        chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this); // remember this :) !
    }
}
```